# Setting max width and height while vertically and horizontally centering a position absolute element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, centering

I'm trying to center a div while satisfying several other conditions.

My UI is a set of tiles that's dynamically added but has fixed widths.

I want the set of tiles to always be centered. Vertically and horizontally (v & h).

It should also not exceed a certain width. For this example let's say the max width is 400px.

If the div exceeds 400px while adding tiles into it, it should break the next tiles into a different line. When that happens, the div should get centered (v & h) again.

If the div doesn't exceed 400px (less tiles), the tiles should still be centered v & h.

When the tiles container exceeds the height of the screen, it should become scrollable. This should happen in a way that the first tile will rest on the top and the tiles at the bottom should be hidden.

Here is a sketch of what I mean:

Red tile is the first tile.

[image]

So what I did to achieve this is I made the tile container position absolute and gave it a max width and a max height.

```
.tile-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
  border: 2px solid green;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This way it's always v & h centered, it scrolls when max height is reached, it centers v & h when there are only few tiles.

But the problem is, it doesn't reach it's max-width.

In the fiddle example I've attached, the max width of the container is 400px, but it stops expanding after 294px.

If I use flex to do this, it messes up the scrollable part where the first tile should rest on the top.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgu30dop/).

Answer (score 0):

Change your scss as follow:

```
.tile-container {
border: 2px solid green;
max-width: 400px;
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;
}

.container {
border: 2px solid;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Here's updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4w27ofy/)

Comment: Hi. When the width is set 100% it won't center the tiles when there are only one or two. Meaning the "max width not reached" scenario in my diagram doesn't work.